# Change GitLab SSH host

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, hostname

I installed GitLab a little while ago using the Omnibus package.

When I create projects using the Gitlab web UI everything works fine.

What I would like to change is the SSH hostname displayed on the top of the project's page.

For example, my actual host name is "git@**xxxx**:group/repo.git", and I would like it to be "git@**yyyy**:group/repo.git".

I have changed the "host" configuration in my `config/gitlab.yml` and the hostname in `/etc/hostname` and then run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure"` but the SSH hostname is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

The [issue 1875](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1875) details what need to be done in order to update the hostname:
(it was referenced from the more recent [issue 8396](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8396))

> Open up `config/gitlab.yml` and there are a couple places where it says `localhost`. You can do a search to make sure you get them all.
>
> The first one is towards the top.

```
web:
host:
```

> The second one is towards the bottom (this is the one that will impact the path)

```
git:
path:
```

> Then restart gitlab

```
service gitlab stop; service gitlab start
```

> Turned out that I needed to run

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production
```

> in the /home/gitlab/gitlab folder as user gitlab
> AND
> (I don't know if this was necessary) I changed the order of the `127.0.0.1` line in `/etc/hosts` from:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost gitlab gitlab.domain.com
TO
127.0.0.1 gitlab.domain.com gitlab localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#available-configuration-parameters

GITLAB_SSH_HOST     The ssh host. Defaults to GITLAB_HOST

It is located in the /etc/docker-gitlab/runtime/env-defaults file

At a terminal in the docker container:

```
grep SSH_HOST /etc/docker-gitlab/runtime/env-defaults                                                                                                                                              
GITLAB_SSH_HOST=${GITLAB_SSH_HOST:-$GITLAB_HOST}
```

Here you could change:
    -$GITLAB_HOST 
to
    -myhost.wherever.com

or you could change the default for GITLAB_HOST from "localhost"

```
:/home/git/gitlab# grep _HOST /etc/docker-gitlab/runtime/env-defaults                                                                                                                                                 
GITLAB_HOST=${GITLAB_HOST:-localhost}
```

to

```
GITLAB_HOST=${GITLAB_HOST:-myhost.wherever.com}
```

No matter how many time you change the

config/gitlab.yml

it will overwrite the value with thoes from env-defaults or the docker run --env  'GITLAB_HOST=myhost.wherever.com'

You can also use a .env file and --env-file at the docker run:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e-env-env-file